# How can I use arithmetic right shifting with an unsigned int?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This is a homework question.

I need to convert an unsigned 8-bit number to a 32-bit signed one.

For example I have this unsigned 8-bit number: `1111 1010`

So in 32-bit signed it should be `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010`

How can I do this? I know that `>>` only pads with 1's when it is a signed int so I could just cast it to a signed int before bit shifting right.

The only thing is is that I have restrictions on my problem which state that I need to make a function that "uses only left and right shifts, along with one subtraction".

Comment: Cast it to signed. (Before anyone calls me out on this: Yes I know it's IB, but show me a single environment where it doesn't work.)

Comment: Ik that will work but as I said in the last paragraph, I'm not allowed to do that

Comment: You might find what you need in the answer to [Sign extending an `int` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755571/sign-extending-an-int-in-c), which deals with arbitrary length fields at arbitrary positions in an integer, but you have a nice tame 8-bit field at the end of the integer.

Comment: @adamk33n3r Then you should probably clarify that you're not allowed to cast. Because I didn't pick it up.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm sorry if you didn't see me say it but I said it can only use left and right shifts and one subtraction

Comment: I don't think a cast between integer types of the same size counts as an operation. (it certainly does not in the hardware) But that's probably something your instructor should clarify. (The restrictions you have given strongly suggest that this is a homework assignment.)

Comment: You are right, I was wondering if casting would matter. This assignment is actually from a book and it says "give a correct implementation of the function that uses only left and right shifts, along with one subtraction." I will just use a cast for now, I was just hoping there was someone who knew how to do it without a cast :)

Comment: It should be 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1010

Comment: @AndréPuel No because I'm not just making it bigger bits, I am wanting to interpret it as signed.

Comment: If it was unsigned it was positive, right?

Comment: What I'm doing is extracting these 8 bits from a 32-bit unsigned. So they are unsigned, but I need to interpret them as signed so they should be padded with 1's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned givenByte = 0xFA;              /*This can be any given byte that we want to pad.*/
unsigned foo = (givenByte >> 7) << 8;   /*This leaves us with only the most significant bit of the original byte shifted left by one place.*/
unsigned result = givenByte - foo;
```

This should return a result similar to the signed arithmetic shift except these operations are performed on an unsigned integer and use only shifts and one subtraction.

```
givenByte = 1111 1010
foo       = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
result    = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010
```

This question comes up every once in a while in CMU textbooks and in other curricula that adopt a similar style which is how I came across this question. Took some time but this method is neat and can be applied to other cases where we need arithmetic right shifts without explicit casting (which is how I believe the question was framed).

Answer (score -1):

Casting it via a signed 8 bit should do the trick?

```
uint8_t start = 0xFF;
int32_t end = (int8_t)start;
```

Or are you not allowed to do that within your homework assignment?

In that case, shifting up and then down will work, due the right shift doing sign-extension.

```
uint8_t start = 0xFF;
int32_t end = (start << 24) >> 24;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I mentioned that I can't use casting

Comment: @adamk33n3r do you see why the shifting works? Signed right shifts behave as though the highest bit is "stuck" at its current value, so if you set it to the high bit of the byte, then shift it right, it will "extend" that high bit across the int.

Comment: That is something that I thought of, actually, but right-shifting an unsigned integer just pads it with 0's and therefore not interpreted as negative in 32-bit

Comment: @Brendan but `start` is unsigned so it wont extend the 1

Comment: @adamk33n3r this does actually work as intended on gcc, I haven't tried it elsewhere.  As Brendan says, this is implementation defined.

Answer (score -3):

You need a proper 32 bit mask. and than set the right most 8 bit of the mask as your 8 bit unsigned int. This will give you the result.

At first yuo should try some code yourself and then try to seek for help.

Comment: I actually have tried some code, for a like an hour actually :/ what do you mean by "proper" 32 bit mask? My problem is just getting it to work for both positive and negative values...

Comment: @adamk33n3r As it is right now, this answer does in fact make little to no sense. So you're right to be confused. Because I am too...

Comment: As your original int is 8 bit unsigned int. So at the result 32 bit int the left most 24 bits will always remain same. that is I am calling a mask.